# Automatically copy cell value to a fixed location as user clicks cells in Google Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I've got an Excel workbook that I converted to Google Sheets. In the Excel version, it has a macro. The VB code is as follows:

```html
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Excel.Range)
[K3] = ActiveCell
End Sub
Private Sub Commandbutton1_Click()
ActiveWorkbook.FollowHyperlink _
Address:="https://www.url.com"
End Sub
```

I'm at a loss as to where to begin to convert this to Apps Script.

EDIT: I'm making progress. The code below is doing what I want, I just have to manually run the script.

```
 function myFunction() {
  var ss= SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var s=ss.getActiveSheet();
  var r= s.getActiveCell();
  var v= r.getValue();
  var r2=s.getRange("A40");
  r2.setValue(v);
}
```

How do I make the script run every time I click in a different cell?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This Apps Script [simple trigger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers) should match the functionality of your `Worksheet_SelectionChange` VBA code:

```
function onSelectionChange(e) {
  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange('K3').setValue(e.range.getValue());
}
```

To activate the function, enter it in **Tools > Script editor** and save, then go back to the spreadsheet and refresh it with `Control+R` (on a Mac, `⌘R`). The function will then update the value in `K3` as you select cells in the sheet.

The sheet refresh is required because of [issue #178615259](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/178615259). Star the issue if you would like to see it fixed.

Comment: Is there any way I can share the spreadsheet as view only and still have the script run?

Comment: No, but you can use **Data > Protect sheet** even when you share the spreadsheet as "can edit". See https://stackoverflow.com/a/67262439/13045193 for an explanation why the script will not work when the spreadsheet is view-only.